# Route 2 devices through a WIndows's PC and out to the broadband router

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing, openvpn

- Home LAN 192.168.0.1/24
- Router 192.168.0.1
- Home server 192.168.0.10
- Home server runs Win7 x64 Ult and OpenVPN client and shares
  media,docs via SMB

Question...

I have a couple of Fire TV devices that I want to connect to the internet via the OpenVPN client on the home server.

Notes

- The home server has a 2nd LAN adapter not currently in use
- Its important the Fire TVs can access the SMB shares on the home
  server
- Its important the Fire TVs reach the internet via OpenVPN on home
  server

Is this possible? Perhaps set the Fire TVs to static IP and set their gateway to one of the home server's LAN adapters? After that I'm lost!

Any advice would be welcome. I suppose another way of phrasing this is, can I use windows ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on the home server PC but turn off the DHCP part of it?